# Potential issue related to React hooks asked for job interview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

So I have a React job interview and have this piece of code in my assignment to close and modal box:

```
const App = (): ReactElement => {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const renderApp = (): ReactElement => {
    if (isOpen) {
      return <FeedbackForm onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />;
    }

    return <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open modal</button>;
  }

  if (isOpen) {
    return <>
      <div className='App'>
        <FeedbackForm onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
      </div>
    </>
  }

  return <>
    <div className='App'>{renderApp()}</div>

  }

export default Feedback;
```

So here I have an `App` component that has a `Modal` component and a simple hook that has a boolean value that indicates if the modal is open or not. The modal starts off as closed, so the initial value is `false`. The button to open the modal is separate from the button that has to close the modal. The button to close the modal is within the `Modal` component while the button to open it is in the `App` component. Because they're both separate buttons, they can explicitly set the value to either `true` or `false`.

Now, on this topic, I received this question from the code reviewer:

`Could you explain the potential issue of the following code?`

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
```

I can't exactly see the problem in this snippet. I've tried running it with a button that calls `toggle()` and I see it updating the state perfectly fine. What is the potential issue the interviewer is talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `toggle` function, we are setting the state based on the current state value. React performs updates in batches and it is a possibility that when we run `toggle()` multiple times, the state is not updated for each subsequent run. So, to make sure that we don't lose the state updates from the previous runs, we can do something like the following:

```js
const toggle = () => setIsOpen((prevIsOpen) => !prevIsOpen);
```

Now, in your scenario, it might not happen because we are showing/hiding modal based on toggle click which changes the views completely, but we can't be sure and can't take chances for production deployment. If it were something else, like showing/hiding of expansion panel, sidebar, etc. then the issue would be easily visible if you clicked toggle button simultaneously, with minimal delay between clicks.

Comment: Is there a particular problem with wrapping setIsOpen in a toggle function? Is it only a potential issue that we pass isOpen to that function?

Comment: The issue is with `setIsOpen`. We can't be sure when it will update the `isOpen` property. If initially `isOpen=true`, and then, if we do `setIsOpen(!isOpen);setIsOpen(!isOpen);`, then,it won't be `true` again. It is because, React will record the updates in a list and then perform them all at once. So,the updates list will be something like `updates=[false,false]` and the end result will be `false`. Had we used `setIsOpen((prevIsOpen) => !prevIsOpen)`,then the update list would be something like `updates=[false,true]` and the end result be `true`. It's because prevIsOpen points to prev State.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I remember I read somewhere that React updates state in an update list with setState and that hooks basically don't have a list and update the single value that needs to be updated right away. Could you elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: The idea is that React performs updates in batches and the same is true for Hooks. This is done regardless of what the value of the state is. You can think of `setState` as a dispatcher in redux. It just dispatches the action/updated state.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for your help :)